# How to check which checkbox is checked and save the data into database using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 4 different checkboxes and when I check one(or two, or three, or all) I want to save some data into a database with a click on the button "Save". I'm using angular.
How I can do this?
I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="addMode1" style="display: none;">
<div class="form">
<form ng-submit="createReason(reasonsForm1.$valid)" name="reasonsForm1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="database_address">Name of reason:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="reasonname" placeholder="Име основание за добавяне" />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p>Using in::</p>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="all">Buy<br>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="all">Sell<br>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="all">PKO<br>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="all">RKO
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cnlbtn1" type="button">Cancel</button>

     <!--ng-click="createUser()"-->
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Добавяне на нов</button>-->
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And Angular code(createReason function which saves data from input box into the database):

```
$scope.createReason=function()
    {
        var objectToSave = {
            name: $scope.reasonname,
        };
            defaultAdapter.query('INSERT INTO reasons(name) VALUES(:name)',

              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });
    }
```

Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like AngularJS instead of Angular. Might want to change the tag, and add a JavaScript tag as well.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you give me an example? I can't understand you.

Comment: Never mind. Someone already edited the tags for you.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen What you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSqa5.png)

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item1']"  /> Testing</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item2']" /> Testing 2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" ng-model="testModel['item3']" /> Testing 3</label><br />
```

> After this on submit check the testModel index value which one is true or false then send that value in database.
>   try this i hope its helpful to you

Comment: if((testModel['item1']) || (testModel['item2']) || (testModel['item3']) || (testModel['item4']) == true){//insert into database}. Is this the right function for checking which value is true ?

Comment: if you insert data one by one then you should check each item value if true then insert in database or push true item in array then execute a loop and insert item in data base.